# Literal does not match format string in date duration in oracle

Tags: oracle

i am facing problem  kindly help me my code is

```
SELECT 'NULL' AS sender_mobile,
       ci.str_identification AS receiver_mobile,
       TO_CHAR (cc.dat_creation, 'YYYYMMDD') AS datee,
       TO_CHAR (cc.dat_creation, 'hh24:Mi:ss') AS timee
FROM   pbxhbl.agent_details ad
       INNER JOIN pbxmob.customers_identifications ci
         ON ad.id_customer = ci.id_customer
       INNER JOIN pbxmob.customers_credentials cc
         ON ci.id_customer = cc.id_customer
       INNER JOIN pbxmob.credential_types ct
         ON cc.id_credential_type = ct.id_credential_type
WHERE  cc.dat_creation BETWEEN '21-August-2015 06:00:00 PM'
                           AND '21-August-2015 06:59:59 PM';
```

Comment: You can help us help you by simplifying your query and isolating the part that fails.

Comment: cc.dat_creation part giving me error "Literal does not match format string"

Comment: what is the datatype of cc.dat_creation?

Answer (score 1):

You'll be better off if you are explicit about your date format. Here is an example that does the same thing as your query:

```
  where cc.DAT_CREATION
between to_date('2015-08-21 18:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
    and to_date('2015-08-21 18:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: will it handle pm and am i don't need 24 hour format

Comment: In this case, I didn't bother because I am using the 24-hour format.  But you can use the 12-hour format with A.M./P.M. if you choose to do that.  You just need to be explicit about which format you want to use. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#i34924) for the different ways you can define your format.